# MySQL join column with blank space

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, join

Table a:

```
phone_number
+123456789000_
+123456789001
+123456789002_
+123456789003
+123456789000
```

The _ at the end of some phone numbers represents a blank space

Table b:

```
phone_number
+123456789000
+123456789002
```

Table b contains the phone_numbers from table a that had a space. The blank space was trimmed.

I need to check if the phone was not added twice on table a(one with a space character and without the space character).

I tried:

```
SELECT a.phone_number FROM a
JOIN b ON a.phone_number = b.phone_number;
```

But it returns all existing phone numbers in b. What I wanted to get from the example above is +123456789000

Thanks.

Comment: Update the table, have those trailing blanks removed! (Sanitize your data!)

Comment: If you want to check if the phone was added twice to table `A`, why do you need table `B` for ?

Comment: If you only want to get the numbers which are in the table b and also be present in the table a you can use `SELECT a.phone_number FROM a
WHERE a.phone_number IN (SELECT b.phone_number FROM b)`.

Comment: I don't need to use table B. I thought it would be easier that way. Maybe a selfjoin?

Comment: This does not work:     SELECT a.phone_number FROM a WHERE a.phone_number IN (SELECT b.phone_number FROM b) returns all records in b

Comment: I'm not sure if the IN Clause ignores whitespaces. But it should not do that. The statement is equivalent to a SELECT like: `SELECT a.phone_number FROM a WHERE a.phone_number='+123456789000' OR a.phone_number='+123456789002'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a self-join instead:

```sql
SELECT t1.phone_number 
FROM a AS t1
JOIN a AS t2 ON t1.phone_number = CONCAT(t2.phone_number, '_');
```

**Edit:**

The previous query looks for an underscore character in `a` table. To detect duplicate phone numbers based on *trailing space characters* you can use this query instead:

```sql
SELECT phone_number
FROM a 
GROUP BY RTRIM(phone_number)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd8d0e/2)

Comment: I don't think this would work. Maybe I was not so clear.
So in table a i have unique phone_numbers but some of these were added with a trailing blank space. I need to find if the phone was added twice on table a(one with a space character and without the space character). Table B is not really needed

Thanks

Comment: @andresg3 Well, it does work with the sample data provided. If it doesn't, then can you please describe what is the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [trim function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to remove the white spaces while joining.

```
SELECT b.phone_number, count(*) as cnt
FROM b
JOIN a ON TRIM(a.phone_number) = b.phone_number
GROUP BY b.phone_number
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

Comment: You might want to `GROUP BY`